# Firestore database migration to EU

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have a desktop app using Firebase that I created 5 years ago, with a lot of customers. I would like to migrate all Firestore, Functions and Storage to EU, because is where all the customers are.

I wouldn't like to create a new project and copy all the data there, because I would need to force an update to all my customers, and in most of them the app is installed in Windows Servers with difficult access.

As now there is multiple databases support, I thought of backing up (default) database, delete it and create a new (default) database in EU. Like this, in the desktop app I wouldn't need to change anything and I'll have the free tier. But I came across this limitation in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-databases):

> Firestore function triggers v1 and Firestore event triggers may stop working after the database is deleted, even if a new database is created with the same name.

I use Cloud Functions triggers and event triggers in my app. If they stop working, will it be temporarily?

Is it a good approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply re-deploy the functions after you create and populate a new database. The functions should then use the new one and not the old one.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that in a test project first